# Calculating autocorrelation function with Python

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, correlation

All that I am trying to do is to calculate the auto correlation of an array jx for which I am using the following formula,

[image: autocorrelation formula]

where n is the time at which I wish to calculate the autocorrelation function, `Mt` is the maximum time and `tk` are time steps running from `1` to `Mt-n`.

This is the code that I have written. I am checking my program with a simple array `jx=linspace(1,10,20)`. I am also making the program save the autocorrelation values for different `n` and plot them with `n`.

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import*

jx=linspace(1,10,20)

Mt=len(jx)

def Hcacf(n):
    Sum=0.0
    coeff1=0
    while coeff1 < (Mt-n) :
        Sum = Sum + jx[coeff1]*jx[coeff1+n]# + jy[coeff1]*jy[coeff1+n]
        coeff1=coeff1+1
    avg = Sum*1.0 / (Mt-n)
    return avg

autocorrelation=[]
for n in linspace(0,Mt-1,Mt):
    ac=Hcacf(n+1)
    autocorrelation.append(ac)

lag=linspace(0,Mt-1,Mt)
plot(lag,autocorrelation,marker='o')
show()
```

The output it returns is this:
[image]

But it also returns the following error messsage:

```
 RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
     avg = Sum*1.0 / (Mt-n)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am completely new to correlation. Can I do it some easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have a division by zero. It works this way:

1) In the line `for n in linspace(0,Mt-1,Mt):` you have `n==Mt-1`,

2) So, in the next line `ac=Hcacf(n+1)` you call the function `Hcacf(Mt)`,

3) But inside this function `Hcacf` you have a line `avg = Sum*1.0 / (Mt-n)`. It is the place where division by zero is possible.

To fix it you can exclude the endpoint of the interval in the first line. Try to replace it by this line:

```
for n in linspace(0, Mt-1, num=Mt, endpoint=False):
```

Comment: You are welcome. For the future: it is really dangerous to divide without zero check. For instance, in this case it would be good to add `if Mt==n: return 0` in the very beginning of the function `Hcacf`.